# Nodejs - Passport - Failed to serialize user into session

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using the following library:

[passport-oauth2-password-grant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-oauth2-password-grant)

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Authenticate to the API (username / password)
2. Get the Access token
3. Get the user profile from the API
4. Log the user in using passport

I'm using the following implementation:

```
PasswordGrantStrategy.prototype.userProfile = function(accessToken, done) {
    return done(null, { real_name: 'Foo Baz', email: 'test@test.com' });

}
passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy({
    tokenURL: 'http://api.local/oauth/token',
    clientID: "2",
    clientSecret: "",
    grantType: "password",
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  return done(null, profile);
}));

function authenticate() {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var username = "email@email.com";
        var password = "password";

        passport.authenticate('password-grant', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })(req, res, next);
    };
}
```

Login to the API using username/password

It's passing the profile into the callback function for the `passport.use(new PasswordGrantStrategy` however, I am getting the following error:

> > Failed to serialize user into session

It should be serializing as I'm passing in a profile and all looks fine. Now does this mean there could be a possible issue with sessions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide serializeUser and deserializeUser method to Passport in order for it to work.

From the official docs:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: `deserializeUser` is never being called though - `serializeUser` is being called, but nothing else.

Comment: What are you using for session storage?

Comment: I just have the following in `app.js`: `app.use(passport.session());`  Which is storing the session?!? I think that's where I'm going wrong but cannot seem to figure out how to handle the sessions

Comment: The session needs to be stored somewhere so that express can compare subsequent requests with the serialized user. Please look into something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session - it's very simple to implement

Comment: I have postgres in the backend in my project so I'm using the package above with another package that writes to postgres: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple

Comment: I've added this in though:

`app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}))` 

Still gives me nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136536/discussion-between-phorce-and-paqash).